# Covert Time Stamp in HIVE

Tags: hive, timestamp

I have a date value (Mon Feb 29 06:01:14 CST 2016) in column. I need to convert this to the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' in hive.

Can any one please help me on this.

Comment: Please tell which language you use.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `unix_timestamp` function which should help you. `to_date(unix_timestamp(your_column, 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z  yyyy'))` This should return a string representing your date.